# What is the name of this Peanuts character wearing a purple shirt and purple/pink shoes?

Tags: peanuts

What is the name of this *[Peanuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanuts)* character wearing a purple shirt and purple/pink shoes?

[image: Peanuts character whose name is unknown - wearing purple shirt and purple/pink shoes]

Comment: [Why was the "What is the name of this Peanuts character?" question removed from the Hot Network Questions list?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/why-was-the-what-is-the-name-of-this-peanuts-character-question-removed-from)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

She is one of the twins from this scene:

[image]

From the [Peanuts.com FAQs](https://www.peanuts.com/faqs):

> **The twin sisters named “Three” and “Four,”** who are most commonly recognized as the bouncy dancing girls in *A Charlie Brown Christmas*, were characters from the daily PEANUTS in the 60’s. They had an older brother named “Five.” In the strips’ story line, their father names them with numbers in protest of society’s ever-growing trend of reducing human lives to statistics. Their last name is actually 95742 – the family’s zip code.

Comment: According to https://peanuts.fandom.com/wiki/3_and_4 3 & 4 or different charachters.

Comment: @grunt "Or" = "are"? They are pointed out to be in the GIF I posted in that article, as well.

Comment: @grunt - If you found this question interesting, you might want to cast a vote here; https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4972/100979

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiEFt.png